# Can not extend a protocol with another protocol in swift

Tags: swift, protocols, option-type

Am trying to implement this piece of code in my project.

```
private protocol AnyOptional {
    var isNil: Bool { get }
}

extension Optional: AnyOptional {
    var isNil: Bool { self == nil }
}
```

I saw it on SwiftBySundell https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/property-wrappers-in-swift/.
But unfortunately am getting this error "**Extension of protocol 'Optional' cannot have an inheritance clause**". Although when I tried the same code on a playground it worked just fine. Any idea why?

Comment: From the error message, the compiler seems to think `Optional` is a protocol, when it's actually an enum. This makes me think there's maybe some protocol with the same name of `Optional` defined either in your own code or some third-party module you've imported. Try changing `Optional` to `Swift.Optional` to see if that removes the error and let us know.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler you are right, I found an Optional protocol in a third party module. Thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that the `Optional` type name isn't being overridden by a third-party module (or your own module even). If it is, then you can use `Swift.Optional` instead to refer to the `Optional` enum built into Swift.